# Prepositional phrases vs participle phrases

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-request, prepositional-phrases, participle-phrases

After eating rice in the kitchen, I usually go to school.

vs

Eating rice in the kitchen,  I usually go to school.

In either sentence , After eating rice in the kitchen, eating rice in the kitchen, and in the kitchen are what type of phrase? Are both sentences same in meaning?

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence is grammatical and has the meaning, "I usually go to school after eating rice in the kitchen" (pretty self-explanatory - not sure how else to paraphrase this).

I think what's going on in the second sentence is a dangling modifier - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_modifier

What is "After eating rice in the kitchen" modifying? This sentence doesn't really make sense. It seems to be saying "I usually go to school *while* eating rice in the kitchen" - which is not really possible. Unless the school is in the kitchen. But even if that were the intended meaning, this is not a way to say it that sounds coherent.